# How To Show String Alignment?

Tags: python

I am nearly done with this program I am just a little stuck on the last part here. 
when run the program will ask for two strings. These are then compared to see the minimum edit distance. Deletions and insertions are a cost of 1, substitutions (delete and insert) are then a cost of 2.

IE quickly and quicker have a distance of 4 because the last two letters would need to be substituted to go from one to the other.

What I am having trouble with is showing the alignment. I want to show like:

```
q u i c k l y
          s s
q u i c k e r
```

to show the two substitutions and where they would be. this would also go for deletions and insertions.

Here it is so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from sys import stdout

def  Edit_Distance(target, source):


n = len(target)
m = len(source)

distance = [[0 for i in range(m+1)] for j in range(n+1)]

for i in range(1,n+1):
    distance[i][0] = distance[i-1][0] + insertCost(target[i-1])

for j in range(1,m+1):
    distance[0][j] = distance[0][j-1] + deleteCost(source[j-1])

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,m+1):
       distance[i][j] = min(distance[i-1][j]+1,
                            distance[i][j-1]+1,
                            distance[i-1][j-1]+substCost(source[j-1],target[i-1]))
return distance[n][m]

def substCost(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return 0
    else:
        return 2

def insertCost(x):
    return 1

def deleteCost(x):
    return 1


# User inputs the strings for comparison
word1 = raw_input("Enter A Word: ")
word2 = raw_input("Enter The Second Word: ")

# Simple conditional that will set the length of the range loop below based on the longest string
if (word2 >= word1):
    x = len(word2)
else:
        x = len(word1)

# x is then the longest string length so that we have the perfect length range loop
# stdout.write allows us to print multiple things on the same line, instead of tabbing down a line each time
print ("The minimum edit distance between S1 and S2 is: ", Edit_Distance(word1,word2))

print list(word1)
for i in range(x):
    if(word1[i] != word2[i]):
        print("D")

print list(word2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your question is only how to print the "D" aligned, you should look at the

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

page of the python documentation, where you can find how to format a string (which is what you are asking for, if I understand).

Btw, just an hint on how to print aligned (given that the code work well): why don't you use a list to store the "D" in the loop ?